# How to load image that fails with 'Unable to load asset:...'

Tags: flutter

My flutter app does not show the album art of my music files that I'm trying to load with `AssetImage()`.
I debugged all the way down to `asset_bundle.dart` and `asset` is `null` as you can see in this debugging screenshot:
[image: Debugging shows asset is null] 
When I check out that image file on my phone and open it with any image displaying app it works.
Could the fact that the file ending is missing be the problem?
If so, how can I tell my app to try to interpret such files without a file ending as .png?

If you're curious about the exact code of the project: [here](https://github.com/KarimElghamry/chillify/blob/652bfb8203b0696a16b64e575961ffe6e37ac08a/lib/src/ui/now_playing/album_art_container.dart#L29)

Comment: Please add your code for AssetImage(). What is the location of the asset?

Comment: @Sebastian the location that I pass into `AssetImage(<locationString>)` is seen in the screenshot `/storage/....` - AssetImage is not my own code, it's just from the `import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';` lib